# Get the value from many radiobuttons inside a table

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

First I create a table with n number of rows and each one of them contains two radio buttons. I need to get all the id from the table row selected and the option selected. I mean if the user selected yes or no.

```
<table border='1' style='width:100%'>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Confirm Order?</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='56'>
        <td>".$date." </td>
        <td>".time." </td>
        <td>".$prog." </td>
        <td>
            <input type='radio' name='prog1' />NO
            <input type='radio' name='prog1' />SI</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now what I got so far is getting the ids from the rows checked. Like this:

```
var idss = [];
$(':radio:checked').each(function(index) {
    var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    idss.push($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
});

$(function test() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: {
      idss: idss
    }
  });
```

How can I get an array with all ids where 'no' was selected, and one array with all the ids where 'yes' was selected.

Comment: Why would you want to pass a JS array to PHP?

Comment: to use that information inside a PHP, update databases and such.

Comment: You need to pass a `key:value`  string.  key=value&key2=value2...

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7w2df640/

This is the js:

```
function getArray(){
    ar = {};
    $(".datarow").each(function(i,o){
        ar[$(o).attr("id")] = $(o).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val()
    });
    console.log(ar);
}
```

For the html, you have to add a class to the rows:

```
<tr class="datarow" id='56'>
```

and also add a value to the radio:

```
<input type='radio' name='prog1' checked value="no" />
```

In the end you will get an array exactly as you wanted:

```
Object {56: "si", 57: "no"}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: shoot, I didn't express myself correctly. I don't want an array with the id and the selected value, what I need is two separate arrays. One containing all the ids from the radio selected with 'no', and another one containing the ids from the selected yes.

Comment: No worries. The updated fiddle creates two arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/7w2df640/1/